# $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution: Iso-density manifold. What else?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let X be a random variable that follows an $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution with mean vector $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and covariance matrix the $n\times n$ symmetric positive matrix $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$. The probability density function, $f_X\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}_+$, is given by
$$
f_X(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\lvert\Sigma\rvert^{1/2}}
\operatorname{exp}\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)\right\}.
$$

What is desired is to define an appropriate manifold that describes sufficiently (geometrically) the above distribution.

For instance, the iso-density locus (ellipsoid) of points that are described by a fraction, $\alpha$, of the maximum density, which is equal to
$$
f_X^{max}=f_X(\mu)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\lvert\Sigma\rvert^{1/2}},
$$
is given as follows, by demanding that
$$
f_X(\mathbf{x})=\alpha f_X^{max},
$$
or
$$
\operatorname{exp}\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)\right\}
=
\alpha.
$$
After logarithming, we obtain the following equation of an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid
$$
\mathcal{E}\colon (\mathbf{x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)=\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right).
$$
Now, if we set $\alpha=1-0.997=0.003$, then (I believe that) we get a pretty good illustration of what the distribution looks like. First, is that true? Does it seem reasonable?

Second, what would be another (if the above is indeed correct) way of describing the "shape" of the above distribution? For example, is there any way of finding out **what is the manifold (ellipsoid) which encloses a fraction (say the 99.7%) of the total population of the distribution**?

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear, possibly due to some mistaken analysis of the maths involved. "First, is that true?" What is true? "Does it seem reasonable?" Reasonable in order to do what? "what is the manifold (ellipsoid) which encloses a fraction..." There are many of them, which one should we select?

Comment: @Did, first of all, what I actually need to do is to obtain an ellipsoid which is characteristic of the "shape" of the distribution. So, The questions "is that true", etc, concern my first attempt which is to find an iso-density manifold, as I explain above. But, I am not sure if this is a reasonable ellipsoid in terms of what I need to show. Am I more clear now? Thanks!

Comment: Let $E_h=\{x\mid({x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}({x}-\mu)=h\}$. Then each ellipsoid $E_h$ with $h\gt0$ fully determines $\mu$ and $\Sigma$. In this sense, to specify that a given ellipsoid is an iso-density curve is enough to determine the density itself. About your other problem (choose $h$ such that the probability of the inside of the ellipsoid $E_h$ is $1-\alpha$), I would say that there is no handy approach to solve it except when $\Sigma=\sigma I_n$ with $\sigma\gt0$. Try to write down the equations when $\Sigma^{-1}=[[1,0]|[0,2]]$ and you will see that already this simple case leads to a mess...

Comment: To sum up, either the equation $$\iint\mathrm e^{-x^2-y^2}\mathbf 1_{x^2+2y^2\leqslant h}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=(1-\alpha)\pi$$ can be solved for $h=h(\alpha)$, then one can solve your problem (and I am missing an argument), or it cannot and then you are lost. Sorry...

Comment: Thanks @Did for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia: "... about $99.7\%$ [of the mass of a Gaussian distibution] are within three standard deviations. This fact is known as the $68-95-99.7$ (empirical) rule, or the $3$-sigma rule."

Based on that, and the fact that you can define ellipoids using the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, you should determine the length of each eigenvector according to the respective eigenvalue (i.e., its square root). In other words, the length of each eigenvector should be equal to three times the square root of its respective eigenvalue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you propose is something that I've been thinking about, but I think it needs to be studied more thoroughly. I will return later with some note on that. By the way, thanks a lot!